# $\{U_{n}\}$ is increasing and $\{V_{n}\}$ is decreasing and $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} V_{n}-U_{n}=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I've studied a result (or theorem) on sequences in my home country and I don't seem to find this theorem in English books.
It goes like this:

Let $\{U_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $\{V_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be two sequences

If:

- $\{U_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is monotone increasing
- $\{V_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is monotone decreasing
- $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} V_{n}-U_{n}=0$

$\{U_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $\{V_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ are called "adjacent", and they both have the same finite limit.

Could you please tell me what this result (or theorem) is called in English?

Thanks a lot

Comment: *Squeeze theorem*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem

Comment: In the link it is stated for functions, but of course the same result holds for sequences.

Comment: The squeeze theorem could possibly be used in the proof of this one. But I don't think that this one is the Squeeze theorem...

Comment: It's not a squeeze since no limit is assumed. It's sort of a direct result of monotone convergence and boundedness.

Comment: I did a bit of research and I found that in France it's considered a theorem. But I don't seem to find it even as a result in English references. I think I will prove it each time I need to use it. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_des_suites_adjacentes

Comment: This vaguely resembles nested interval principle but seems formulated in a different manner. While proving nested interval principle (or a special case of this principle) we do get sequences as mentioned in your theorem.